# Show / Hide buttons in RecyclerView adapter from Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have some `RecyclerView` item with invisible button and I would like to change all button visibility from Activity. Like this:

[image: Before]

[image: After clicked Edit Button in Activity]

Please help me.

Comment: are you populating this recycerview from a database?

Comment: @BiGGz yes.....

Comment: define an interface in the Activity that the RecyclerView implements, then in the method implementation, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to force a reload, and have some sort of a boolean that specifies whether to set button visibility to visible or invisible in `bindView()`. This boolean can be initialized by the interface call from the Activity. Make sense? If so il post an answer with a bit of code

Comment: @BiGGZ Thank you so much. It's worked!

Comment: Don't see any difference in both images.Both looks same

Answer (score 11):

Why don't you create a method inside your RecyclerAdapter which will activate the button when a certain action happens in the Activity. Let's say an activity named `activateButtons` like this:

```
public void activateButtons(boolean activate) {
    this.activate = activate; 
    notifyDataSetChanged(); //need to call it for the child views to be re-created with buttons.
}
```

Now, inside your `onBindViewHolder`, do something like this:

```
if (activate) {
   buttons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
   buttons.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

and now, the final step, call the `activateButtons` method from Activity on an action:

```
editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         adapter.activateButtons(true);  
      }
});
```